# Where do WordPress and other blogging engine questions belong?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, scope

Jeff commented in my question about [Super User being a dumping ground](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10219/is-superuser-a-stackoverflow-dumping-ground), that WordPress questions don't belong on Super User

> I disagree; that question is not really computer related. It's wordpress website support related.

Just now a "[is there a blogging engine that handles code highlighting well](https://superuser.com/questions/14768/is-there-a-blog-engine-that-handles-computer-code-highlingting-well)" question that got migrated to superuser.com from serverfault.com.

So does the ping pong now commence? Where should these questions live, SU or SF?

Comment: Related: [WordPress questions - Where to ask now that we have Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58697/289691)

Answer (score 2):

If it's some programming related aspect of WordPress, then it belongs on Stack Overflow.

If it's a question *about* the platform itself without a code-related point of view, it belongs on Super User. This case is where your example above would fall.

If it's about what you need to host WordPress, it could belong on Server Fault.

Answer (score 0):

If the question asks about recommendations on blogging software, blogging tools or what's good to have, then it belongs dead and buried.

Same if they're "looking for something" and more so if it is definitely  the kind of question that would trigger answers based on popularity and rep-whoring.

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems with the trilogy is that only one of the sites is really **well** defined: Stack Overflow. Questions (and answers) are programming or software development related.

Server Fault is for IT administrators and operators, and questions there are [generally] about implementing technology to fulfill some business function. This is supposed to be "server focused", but more and more IT organizations are outsourcing technology to "the cloud". For example, email is hosted by Google Apps, company blogging is done on Wordpress/TypePad. It is still up to IT to support and facilitate the usage of such outsourced technologies.

More and more companies do this, and it is perfectly valid to ask these kinds of questions on Server Fault. It may not be a clear that someone is asking because they want to implement it for their company. For the "code highlighting" question, they could be publishing blog entries about cool things their company is making. We don't know that. Rather than immediately moving a question, why don't moderators at least **comment** on the question, **as is encouraged** to get clarification about the intent.

Further, it is not valid to assume that everyone is using all three (four) sites. The person who asked that question doesn't have a Super User ID.

Comment: "It may not be a clear that someone is asking .." then the question is unclear, and deserves to be closed. I haven't seen many (any, in fact!) examples of what you're describing on SF. Can you provide URLs?

Comment: Closed right away without even commenting? At least give the person asking a chance to make the question clear. The question about syntax highlighting in this question is an example of what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would interpret what goes where using wordpress as an example:

Enhancing or building themes, or hacking on Wordpress itself or developing plugins etc belongs in Stackoverflow.

Installing, configuring and supporting installations of the software belongs on serverfault.

Using the software as an end user or "which blogging platform should I use" questions belong on superuser.