# WordPress questions - Where to ask now that we have Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, wordpress-se

How do I decide where to ask about WordPress questions? There is [an old question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18941/where-should-i-ask-wordpress-questions), but there are now two additional sites - *[Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/tour)* and *[Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour)*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may want to support the [WordPress Development](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1500/wordpress-answers) proposed site on [Area 51](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Exchange#History). I would anticipate this to be a very useful site.

Comment: The proposed site launched. And graduated!

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't ask on Wep Applications - WordPress is a software system, not a web application. It appears to be tolerated on Pro Webmasters for now, however there is at least one WordPress Stack Exchange being proposed, so when that opens, the questions might be discouraged on Pro Webmasters.